# Reporting services matrix control colour in excel

Tags: reporting-services, rendering, reportingservices-2005

I have just written a report using the Matrix control in SSRS 2005. I have coloured the rows and columns and when I preview the report the colouring is applied. Same with export to pdf.

Only when I view the exported report in Excel do I get a problem.

The report colours are rendered properly other than the Matrix controls. (they are rendered as Grey)

Is there anything I can do solve this?

I am using SSRS2005 and viewing the xls in Excel 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a colour that is valid in Excel to colur the rows and column?

Comment: I am using one of the default colour schemes.